# Finding the minimum angle in which a function is no longer bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives, physics

I have a differential for a ray of light entering a medium with refractive index n(y), and using Fermat's principle for the path of light - the equation is given as:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt {\frac{\left(1+10^{-4}e^{\left(-\frac{y}{5}\right)}\right)^2}{cos^2(\theta_0)}-1}$$

Where y is the height traveled, and $\theta_0$ is the angle above the x-axis.

I need to find the largest angle $\theta_0$ in which the graph of the function is no longer bounded, i.e. the graph doesn't approach a constant value.

At first I thought it had to do with small angle approximations, where if we take a value of $\theta_0$ that can no longer be approximated to 1,but that doesn't seem to be correct.

My next train of thought was seeing what happens when y approaches infinity, and then finding a condition on $\theta_0$, but that hasn't proven to be fruitful since the resulting function isn't bounded either.

i'd appreciate some insight into the problem

Comment: Are you quite sure in that expression? And what does "angle above the x-axis" mean? It seems to me that if $\cos(\theta_0) < 1$, then you can put a (positive) lower bound on $dy/dx$, which means $y$ cannot be bounded. So the only angle for which it might be bounded is $\theta_0 = 0$. And in fact, from your formula, $\tan\theta_0$ is exactly the limit of $dy/dx$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$. I thought the subscript 0 indicated it was some kind of initial condition, but I can't make sense of it that way.

Comment: There is another term in the denominator but it approximates to 1.  

By angle measured above x-axis I meant it is measured from the x-axis  i.e. http://www.d.umn.edu/~bjohnson/vector/q-x.gif.

The subscript is meant to be the angle in which the ray leaves the origin from. 
The question states that there exists a minimum angle - but I've exhausted all my ideas besides a brute force matlab plot.

Comment: And I think it's exactly because of the term you are neglecting. It wouldn't happen to be a $(1+10^{-4})^2$ next to the $\cos^2$, would it? This is not about small angle approximations at all - things need to be exact here.

Comment: Yep that was it - realized my mistake yesterday. Thanks nick!